# get the modifed list in a map on each iteration

Tags: scala

Language is Scala
Let's say that I have a list of `Position(x,y)` with some move instructions and I want to manage the collisions between them with a functional approach, how can I do that?

Example :

`Point a = [x=1,y=1]` with the instruction to move to `[x=2,y=1]`

`Point b = [x=2,y=2]` with the instruction to move to `[x=2,y=1]`

Your list is `[a,b]` and then you want to apply the function to move them and handling collisions. So in the example above you should notice a collision between b and a ( b trying to go to a's position ). What's the code for that?

What i have now is :

```
list.map(position => position.instruction.move())
```

but it doesn't handle collisions.
I want to do something like

```
list.map(position => position.instruction.move()(list))
```

but the list is only updated at the end of the map so b never collides with a. In fact, the collisions are being verified with the initial values. It is using a position[x=1,y=1] instead of the new a position [x=2, y=1].

It's easy to do it in an iterative way with a for loop but how do you do that in a functional way ?

Comment: This question could be improved. See [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274371/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) and the help section on [mcve] for inspiration.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: list.map(position => position.instruction.move()(list)) i only tried this and faced the problem. I don't know what to do

Comment: What would you do in case of a collision?

Comment: you need to use reduce or fold instead of map - then you can build your updated list as you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a recursive function to check for the modified points so far and try to detect collisions, something like this

```
def moveCollisionAware(l: List[Position]) = {
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def move(l: List[Position], acc: List[Position]): Either[String, List[Position]] = l match {
     case Nil => Right(acc)
     case head :: tail =>
       val newPosition = head.move(2, 1)
       if (acc.contains(newPosition))
         Left(s"Moving $head will clash with an existent position")
       else
         move(tail, acc :+ newPosition)
  }

  move(l, List.empty)
}
```

That is basically what you need (and a good way to understand what's going on), once you are more comfortable with the List API you could use `foldLeft` and achieve the same

Something like

```
positions.foldLeft(Right(List.empty[Position]): Either[String, List[Position]]) {
  case (Right(acc), position) =>
    val newPosition = position.move(2, 1)
    if (acc.contains(newPosition))
      Left(s"Moving $position will clash with an existent position")
    else
      Right(acc :+ newPosition)
    case (e @ Left(_), _) => e
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! You're amazing ! I already knew about folds but this is a very nice trick ! :)

Comment: @IngeniousDev 1) Don't evaluate users, evaluate quality of questions and answers. 2) If you found this answer at least as amazing as Bruno, then consider upvoting it.

Comment: 1) This user gave me his answer, I consider that his answer is a part of his mind. It's the same, don't be upset 2) New account. I can't upvote his answer.